# Values are sometimes overwritten after using strlcpy with char ** type

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to learn C recently to get a better understanding of (comparatively) low-level programming since I usually do most of my work in Python, PHP, Swift, Java, Javascript, etc. I think I understand the concept of pointers and how to allocate/free memory, but in one particular instance I am quite stuck. It seems that sometimes (maybe < 10% of the time) some code I have to test `strlcpy` will produce unexpected results. The other 90+% of the time, it works as intended. Following is the code I'm running with comments describing my intent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void populate(int length, size_t size, char **strings) {
    char test[5] = "test"; //the string we use to populate our incoming array
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) //iterate through the length of the string array
    {
        strings[i] = malloc(sizeof(*strings) * size); //allocate memory for this string to the size of {size}
        strlcpy(*(strings + i), test, size); //copy our test string to the string at index {i} of our array
        printf("%p - ", (void *) strings[i]); //print the address as a dummy check
        printf("String %d: %s\n", i, strings[i]); //confirm our string is being copied as expected
    }
}

int main() {
    int length = 3; //the length of our array of strings
    size_t size = 5; //the length of each string
    char **strings = malloc(sizeof(**strings) * length); //a pointer to a {length}-element array of char pointers
    printf("Start iteration 1\n");
    populate(length, size, strings); //a function which fills **strings with {length} strings of size {size}
    printf("Start iteration 2\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) //iterate through each string to validate the result
    {
        printf("%p - ", (void *) strings[i]); //print the address as a dummy check
        printf("String %d: %s\n", i, strings[i]); //display our string at index {i}
        free(strings[i]); //free the memory of this string
    }
    free(strings); //free the memory of our string array
    return 0;
}
```

I have constructed this in an attempt to better understand the `**` pointer-to-pointer syntax and logic. Everything seems to work fine in that most of the time, I will get the following printout in my console:

```
Start iteration 1
0x7ffd70c027a0 - String 0: test
0x7ffd70c027b0 - String 1: test
0x7ffd70c027c0 - String 2: test
Start iteration 2
0x7ffd70c027a0 - String 0: test
0x7ffd70c027b0 - String 1: test
0x7ffd70c027c0 - String 2: test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Sometimes, however, a few of the values displayed *only* in the second iteration are either incorrect or cause what I presume to be a segmentation fault:

```
Start iteration 1
0x7f9f78f00840 - String 0: test
0x7f9f78f00850 - String 1: test
0x7f9f78f00860 - String 2: test
Start iteration 2
0x7f9f78f00840 - String 0: �x�
0x7f9f78f00850 - String 1: test

Process finished with exit code 11
```

I can't quite figure out why this is happening, though I think based on my results I can safely assume that it is outside of the scope of the `populate` function. Is there an issue with my pointer arithmetic? Am I not allocating enough memory in some case?

Initially, I thought that it might be something to do with the way I was freeing memory at the end of the `main` function, but I looked up a few questions in SO to find that it seems I'm doing it correctly by freeing the inner arrays first (`*strings`) before freeing the outer array (`strings`). Based on the location of the error, though, I still have reason to believe that the issue may be with how I am freeing memory. I just can't figure out what it is I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need a pointer tutorial!

Comment: I've read multiple...

Comment: `*(strings + i)` is much more simply written as `strings[i]`

Comment: Thanks @Schwern I am aware of the subscript syntax as a valid option for accessing the value of the pointer at address `pointer + i`. There is no particular reason I don't use it here, though it shouldn't have any affect on the program execution I don't think.

Comment: @MichaelFourre Yup, it's probably equivalent. It does make the code harder to read, which is important when asking other people questions, and easier to make mistakes, which is important when asking why your code isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I'll go through and change the syntax so that it's easier to read in case other people want to come back to this question. @Schwern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this: `char **strings = malloc(sizeof(**strings) * length);`

Note that you're allocating `sizeof(**strings)`. `char **` dereferenced twice is just a `char`, so `sizeof(**strings)` is 1. So you're only allocating 3 bytes. That's not what you want.

Instead you want `sizeof(*strings)`, the thing being stored in `strings`. That will be a `char *` and will be 4 or 8 depending on if you're 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: This must be right. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Let me check to see if that solves things.

Comment: @MichaelFourre A memory checker like valgrind will catch these sorts of mistakes.

Comment: I was just reading about Valgrind. I think I'll have to go get it.